# Summarize weekly earnings, including empty records

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to summarize weekly earnings for a time management system (PHP/MySQL), but having a lot of trouble with this SQL query. Basically, I need to return sums of earnings for the past 8 weeks including records for weeks with no earnings, but I can't make this work when I add anything into the WHERE clause to narrow it down to specific kinds of tasks. There are three tables involved in this query:

tbltask stores information about tasks, including the date the task is logged, which user did it, how much time should be billed for, and whether the task is billable or not (some are not billable and should be excluded from the earnings calculation)...

```
task_id   task_name        time_est   billable   date_logged   user_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------
223       some task        120        0          2014-12-19    1
224       a billable task  45         1          2014-12-19    2
225       also billable    90         1          2014-12-20    1
```

tbluser stores user information, so i need to join with it to get the payrate per hour...

```
user_id   payrate   
--------------------
1         50
2         75
```

calendar is just a table with a wide range of dates so that I can join with it and produce results for dates with no records.

```
datefield 
--------------------
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
[...]
2025-12-31
```

Below is what I have so far, to give me a total of everyone's earnings by week (starting on a Monday) for the 8 weeks prior to the date in question. This seems to work as expected, but counts all tasks instead of just billable tasks. If there are no tasks logged for any of these weeks, I get records returned with 0 as total_earned, which is important because I need records for the past 8 weeks even if no time is logged.

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) AS first_day, 
SUM( IFNULL( time_est /60 * payrate, 0 ) ) AS total_earned
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN tbltask ON tbltask.date_logged = calendar.datefield
LEFT JOIN tbluser ON tbltask.user_id = tbluser .user_id
WHERE datefield <=  '2014-12-26'
GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) 
ORDER BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

BUT, I need to only add up earnings for tasks that are billable (billable=1). As soon as I add this in, I no longer get weeks with no logs, so there are weeks missing from the records returned.

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) AS first_day, 
SUM( IFNULL( time_est /60 * payrate, 0 ) ) AS total_earned
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN tbltask ON tbltask.date_logged = calendar.datefield
LEFT JOIN tbluser ON tbltask.user_id = tbluser .user_id
WHERE datefield <=  '2014-12-26' AND billable = 1 
GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) 
ORDER BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

I understand why this result makes sense (because there are no billable=1 tasks completed in those weeks, so no record is returned), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to rewrite the query to get what I want. I would also like to write queries that get the earnings for a particular user instead of all users totalled (user_id=1) but of course that gives me the same problem. I think I might need to use a subquery?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

SOLUTION:

In case anyone else ends up struggling with something similar, I used terary's suggestion of IF() to move the billable=1 and user_id=1 logic inside the SUM calculation, instead of putting it in the WHERE clause. This solved my problem because it returns all the empty weeks with a 0 for total earnings instead of skipping those weeks without records. I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but this does work. Here's the resulting query:

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) AS first_day, 
SUM(IF(billable=1 AND user_id=1, time_est /60 * payrate, 0)) AS total_earned
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN tbltask ON tbltask.date_logged = calendar.datefield
LEFT JOIN tbluser ON tbltask.user_id = tbluser .user_id
WHERE datefield <=  '2014-12-26' AND billable = 1 
GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) 
ORDER BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(datefield)-2, 7)) DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me I didn't create the tables the run the queries.  So I can not debug what you have.

However, 
A)
You can create tbltasks.wkyear which which will eleminate the need for one of your tables.
this can be stored via on insert via trigger (maybe default value?). or just write the thing.

B) Well I guess I am uncertain of your goal?
I guess I have half a clue now.

I think the SELECT IF(billiable=1,50,0)  is your friend.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek
 SELECT YEARWEEK('1987-01-01');
        -> 198653

Comment: I don't think I can get the result I want with tbltask.wkyear because I would still have the problem of not being able to get records for weeks with no tasks logged. That's why I have the calendar table, so I can query dates and none will be left out, then fill in the data I have (unless there is a better way to do it, but this is the one that I have found suggested).

Comment: I did manage to get the query to do what I wanted with IF(), thanks! Will update the question with details.

Comment: Yeah - i get now what you are saying.  I think you were working two problems and I was thinking about one and failing to understand the other.  In your case  - because I am lazy and I like things to be all like you know order - if it would work perhaps you can add for the weekyr no task a record indicating - no task billable=0, hours=0.  Just have some program/stored procedure check for existance - and insert - you knw?